# Getting difficulty in reading image from Disk for iphone in Unity

Tags: iphone, ios, unity-game-engine

I am developing a unity app, in which i call webservice for image url and after getting those url, i call one by one url for image downloading and store those images onto disks, and after in some point i read those images from disks and show as texture, but i am getting problem in reading images. It show me Question mark on texture and when i dig more to find out problem i got that i am getting zero of image using www.size and text also nil using www.text. I am doing following for reading and writing images. 
**Writing**

```
if(wwwMarker.isDone)
File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/"+ data.markerName + ".jpg", wwwMarker.bytes);
```

**Reading**

```
//fileurl is string which contain path of file 
fileUrl = (Application.persistentDataPath + "/"+ markerDataObject.markerName + ".jpg");
if(System.IO.File.Exists(fileUrl))
if(www.isDone)
video.mIconPlane.renderer.material.mainTexture = imageToLoadPath.texture;
```

But when i read this code and show render image on texture it show me Question mark image, but when i load images from assets it works perfectly fine. Please help me that where i am doing wrong. I am nee bee in unity so thats why doing silly mistakes. This will be great for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that unity's `WWW` can only dowload and save as textures JPG and PNG images. If you will try to download an image of any other format, you will get a red "?" image as result.

Comment: well, you just need to do something like this: `WWW www = new WWW(pictureURL)`, then, when dowload is ready (there is a flag in WWW class) just take texture from it: `www.texture`. But note, that this property is CLONING dowloaded data, so use it only once.